# free simple webmail that doesn't require javascript?

Tags: email, javascript

Could someone recommend free email service accessible from webmail that doesn't have annoying bloated interface requiring javascript? So far I like gmail because even with js off it still works great - are there any alternatives to gmail in this regard?

Comment: Stick with GMail- it has the best features of any free webmail and, like you said, it works well with javascript off.

Comment: maybe mail2web.   Yahoo has a wap mail option

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because now there is a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SO community which this is more appropriate for at the current moment -- I know the comment from Jeff from 2010 may have been relevant then, but I would say not so much anymore and I've seen other questions closed for this (or similar) reasons for being off-topic so this one is no different even with that comment in case this is why it's still here; I'll do it

Answer (score 5):

I prefer two web applications for this task:

1. [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org) is a very good webmail client for IMAP that is lightweight, simple and stable. Also it is absolutely javascript-free.
2. [Horde](http://www.horde.org/) is a web framework that includes email client with support for filtering messages and viewing on small screens (cellphones), calendar, address books and much more. All parts of framework are configurable and can be easily removed from it if not needed. Also it can synchronize with most desktop applications and mobile devices, especially for contacts and tasks. Although it uses javascript in a few places it can work as well without scripts enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use [FastMail](http://fastmail.fm) because it [does not require JavaScript](http://www.fastmail.fm/pages/fastmail/docs/about.html) or any other malarkey.

FastMail is supported by ad revenues, and places a banner ad at the top of the page.  Only a selfish person would block these ads with AdBlockPlus or similar.</sarcasm>